# Fade out div before leaving page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to fade out some div elements with a class of .card when I click on a link before going to that link. The fade out works but I don't get taken to the linked page. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      linkLocation = this.href;
      $('.card').addClass('fadeOutDown', function() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
      });
  });

});
```

Comment: It is because `$.addClass()` does not accept second argument

Comment: I don't see such `addClass()` sugnature here https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ what am I missing ?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes it does when you use [jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/). Whether or not OP does use jQueryUI may be the problem.

Comment: The cheap-and-dirty solution would be to `setTimeout` changing the window.location based on the duration of the animation.   (I do have to say, as a user, being forced to wait through an animation when I just want to follow a link would be _super_ annoying...)

Comment: Added a delay function in soln. same as setTimeout but jQuery, you can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addClass` signature is wrong. Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          linkLocation = this.href;  
         $('.card').addClass('fadeOutDown').delay(1000).queue(function(){
           window.location = linkLocation;
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes how about a setTimeout wrapping that window.location for the duration of the fade out animation?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes is right - this answer doesn't work.

Comment: Yes you are right.. slipped that point. Changed and added a delay, check now.

Comment: You'll need to bind to the unload event.

Comment: @i-CONICA I think OP only wants to do this when the user clicks on a link and not everytime the user leaves the page.

Comment: So you just set the selector to only select anchor tags when setting up the binding.